# How to do multiple insert after select in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, insert-select

I want to do something like

insert into table
 (  A, 
    B,
    C
 ) 
(select '1', one.A, one.B from table_1 one)
UNION 
(select '2', one.A, one.B from table_1 one)

Will this call select query twice ? 
Are there any better way of doing this  ?

Comment: yes, it runs select twice.. how could it do anything other than that? you're selecting from two different tables. a join wouldn't be possible, because that'd produce a single `(a,b)`-type record set for the insert, rather than separate `(a),(b)`

Comment: @MarcB, Sorry that I didn't write it correct.  I am selecting from the same table.
What I want to do is :
For every row I selected, I want to insert two rows into another table

Comment: you can't produce rows out of nothing in mysql. if you want two rows inserted, you have to produce two rows, which means running `select` twice.

Comment: moral of the story is: `UNION ALL` is your friend

Comment: Frankly though, I would consider keeping union out of the whole thing. Just do 2 insert stmts

Comment: Another way to return the set is a join operation, between table_1 and an inline view that returns two rows... **`SELECT d.i, o.a, o.b FROM (SELECT '1' AS i UNION ALL SELECT '2') d CROSS JOIN table_1 o`**  (Question is closed, so this can't be left as an answer. Personally, I'd prefer a single SELECT statement to the UNION/UNION ALL operation. I don't know if this can objectively be considered "a better way" or not.)